# I am trying to use sas first.value, but get different results then expected

Tags: sas

I am trying to run this code for a basic presentation:

```
[![DATA a ;
    INFILE DATALINES DSD DLM='|'  ;
    LENGTH Actor_Name $20 ;
    INPUT Actor_Name $ Total ;
    DATALINES ;
    Julie Maze | 1
    Julie Maze | 1
    Julie Maze | 1
    Marry Dryn | 1
    Marry Dryn | 1
    Marry Dryn | 1
    ;
RUN ;

PROC SORT DATA = work.a OUT = a_sorted ;
    BY Actor_Name ;
RUN ;

DATA b ;
    SET work.a_sorted ;
    BY Actor_Name ;
    IF first.Actor_Name
    THEN counter = 1 ;
    ELSE counter + 1 ;
RUN ;][1]][1]
```

I expect to see 6 data lines, where the new column 'counter' would state 1,2,3 and 1,2,3 for each Actor_Name group. But I get 1,2,3 and 1,2,**1**

Comment: Why are your datalines indented?  That will just confuse the SAS programmer and gives stupid text editors a chance to replace spaces with tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 6th sorted data line probably has a control character in it, perhaps a tab?

Running what you posted though gives 1,2,3,1,2,3.  Your actual data lines could have hard space 'A0'x.  Try `PUT name $HEX40.;` to see in log what you actually have.

Comment: No. No control character

Comment: In the 5ht row, I had spaces instead of indent. I will take your comment into consideration, thanks.

Comment: What are "spaces instead of indent"?

Answer (score 1):

Your program works fine for me.

[image]

But of course I ran it in Display Manager which will convert tabs to spaces when the code is submitted.

I would advice to not indent the lines of data.  Having all of those extra spaces just makes it hard to see what is on the line.  It also gives stupid text editors a chance to replace spaces with tab characters.

You should also not indent the DATALINES statement so that both you and the program editor are reminded to start typing in column one.

You also don't need to have an empty step after the end of the data step.

```
DATA a ;
    INFILE DATALINES DSD DLM='|'  ;
    LENGTH Actor_Name $20 ;
    INPUT Actor_Name $ Total ;
DATALINES ;
Julie Maze | 1
Julie Maze | 1
Julie Maze | 1
Marry Dryn | 1
Marry Dryn | 1
Marry Dryn | 1
;
```